# How do you write a cancan ability so can? and accessible_by both work on self referencing HABTM relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am stumped on how to handle this situation using a self referencing HABTM relation, cancan, and ActiveRecord.

I am trying to use **accessible_by** to determine a set of videos that are visible given a relationship between videos and channels, but the resulting SQL has the wrong table name for part of the query.  Here are the relationships:

```
# video.rb
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :channel
end

# channel.rb
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subchannels, :class_name => "Channel", :join_table => "channels_channels", :foreign_key => :parent_id, :association_foreign_key => :subchannel_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parent_channels, :class_name => "Channel", :join_table => "channels_channels", :foreign_key => :subchannel_id, :association_foreign_key => :parent_id
end

# The appropriate channels_channels table exists with subchannel_id and parent_id fields.
```

I need a **cancan ability** to find all public videos that are in public sub-channels of the default channel.  I tried the following:

```
# ability.rb
can :read, Video, :permission => 'public', :channel => {:permission => 'public', :parent_channels => {:name => "Default"}}
```

In the console, when I try this out, I get the following:

```
> Video.accessible_by(Ability.new(nil))
SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" INNER JOIN "channels" ON "channels"."id" = "videos"."channel_id" INNER JOIN "channels_channels" ON "channels_channels"."subchannel_id" = "channels"."id" INNER JOIN "channels" "parent_channels_channels" ON "parent_channels_channels"."id" = "channels_channels"."parent_id" WHERE "videos"."permission" = 'public' AND "channels"."permission" = 'public' AND "channels"."name" = 'Default'
=> []
```

I have some records in place that should result in a video, and, more to the point, would have expected the end of the query to have **"parent_channels_channels"."name" = 'Default'**, but the table is **"channels"** in stead, resulting in the wrong dataset since the SQL is referencing the name of the channel, not the parent channel.

I tried changing the ability as follows to force the table name:

```
    can :read, Video, :permission => 'public', :channel => {:permission => 'public', :parent_channels => {"parent_channels_channels.name" => "Default"}}
```

That results in the correct query, and **accessible_by** returns the right dataset, but then **can?(:read, video)** for a video in that result set results in a runtime error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `parent_channels_channels.name' for #<Channel:0x007fef35593748>
```

How do I specify this ability so it works with both **can?** and **accessible_by**?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from your code whether you are modelling this correctly. Do you really want parent_channels and subchannels to be a HABTM relationship, or even be the same model? Maybe some real-world examples from your app would help me here but it seems like what you want is a parent VideoCategory, and you want HABTM relationships with Channels, which then each have a has_many relationship with videos.

You could then have VideoCategory having a has_many :videos, :through => :channels relationship.

```
class VideoCategory
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels

  has_many :videos, :through => :channels
end

class Video
  belongs_to :channel
end

class Channel
  has_many :videos

  has_and_belongs_to_many :video_cateogories
end
```

It seems like you are trying to make the Channel class do more than be a channel. The concept of parents and children doesn't make a lot of sense in habtm relationships. Generally if you want a parent class and sub classes, then you want a 1-to-many relationship. Many-to-many implies that neither association is the parent class (although this may be different than how you present it in the UI, of course).

If you really must do this as self-referential, have you tried using scopes instead?

```
class Video
  scope :public, lambda do
    joins(:channel).where("videos.permission = 'public' and channels.permission = 'public'")
  end
end
```

It seems that putting the logic into scopes and out of ability.rb might help you better control exactly what SQL gets written -- it removes the layer of abstraction that CanCan is doing.